# Activity force closes

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I am currently starting an activity from within a SurfaceView. The Activity starts up fine (displays an EditText and a button inside a LinearLayout). However, it force closes. It is giving me errors saying ANR in com.thesis.sakurame (which is my package) and also Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut. Any clues as to why this is? Four classes are shown below.

BoardThread.java:

```
public class BoardThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private BoardView boardView;

    private Vector<Blossom> blossomVector;
    private int boxX;
    private int boxY;
    private int boxWidth;
    private int boxHeight;
    private boolean mrun =false;
    private Iterator<Blossom> iterator;

    private static final String TAG = "Debug";

    public BoardThread(SurfaceHolder holder, BoardView boardView2, 
            Vector<Blossom> blossomVector1, Iterator<Blossom> dataIterator,
            int box_x, int box_y, int boxW, int boxH) {

        surfaceHolder = holder;
        boardView=boardView2;

        blossomVector = blossomVector1;
        iterator = dataIterator;
        boxX = box_x;
        boxY = box_y;
        boxW = boxWidth;
        boxH = boxHeight;
    }

    public void startRunning(boolean run) {

        mrun=run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        super.run();
         Canvas canvas;
         while (mrun) {
            canvas=null;
             try {
                 canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                  synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                     //update position
                     //Position(blossomVector, boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                     // draw flowers
                     boardView.onDraw(canvas);
                 }
             } finally {
                     if (canvas != null) {
                     surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                 }
             }
         }
      }

    private synchronized void Position(Vector<Blossom> blossomVector,int box_x, int box_y, 
            int boxWidth, int boxHeight)
    {
        //for(Blossom blossom: blossomVector)
        iterator = blossomVector.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Blossom tempBlossom = iterator.next();
            tempBlossom.UpdatePosition();

        }
    }

}
```

BoardView.java

```
public class BoardView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
    Context mContext;

    // thread initialization
    private BoardThread thread;
    Thread timer;
    Thread timer2;

    // box variables
    Bitmap box = 
        (BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                (getResources(), R.drawable.box));
    private int box_x = 140;
    private int box_y = 378;
    private int boxWidth = box.getWidth();
    private int boxHeight = box.getHeight();

    // storage
    private Vector<Blossom> blossomVector = new Vector<Blossom>();
    Iterator<Blossom> dataIterator = blossomVector.iterator();

    // counters
    private int blossomNum = 0;
    private String score;
    private int currentScore = 0;
    private int lives = 3;

    boolean mode = false;
    boolean game = false;

    OutputStreamWriter out = null;
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;

    private static final String TAG = "Debug";
    final Paint scorePaint = new Paint();

    public BoardView(Context context){
        super(context);

        scorePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        scorePaint.setTextSize(12);
        scorePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);


        //surfaceHolder provides canvas that we draw on
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // controls drawings
        thread = new BoardThread(getHolder(),this, blossomVector, dataIterator, box_x, box_y, 
                boxWidth, boxHeight);

        timer2 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(game == false){
                    uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(5000); // change to be random
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //makes sure the player still has 3 lives left
                while(game == false){
                    uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000); // wait two seconds before drawing the next flower
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } //sleep for 2 seconds
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
        timer2.start();

        //intercepts touch events
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        score = "SCORE: " + currentScore;

        //note: pay attention to order you draw things
        //don't change order or else blossoms will fall
        //on top of box, not "into" it.

        //display the scoreboard
        canvas.drawText(score,240,420,scorePaint);
        // uses a synchronized method to prevent concurrent modification
        DrawBlossoms(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(box, box_x, box_y, null);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        //handles movement of box
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(event.getX() > box_x & event.getY() > box_y & 
                    event.getX() < box_x + boxWidth & event.getY() < box_y + boxHeight)
            {
                mode = true;
            }
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if(event.getX() > box_x & event.getY() > box_y & 
                    event.getX() < box_x + boxWidth & event.getY() < box_y + boxHeight)
            {
                mode = true;
            }
            if(mode == true){
                box_x = (int)event.getX();
            }   

        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            mode = false;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, 
            int format, int width, int height ){
        Log.v(TAG, "Surface Changed");
        //somehow these don't seem to be working
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
        thread.startRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
        Log.v(TAG, "Surface Destroyed");
        //somehow these don't seem to be working

    }

    private Handler uiCallback = new Handler(){
        public synchronized void handleMessage(Message msg){
            //add a new blossom to the blossom Vector!!
            blossomVector.add(new Blossom( 
                (BitmapFactory.decodeResource
                        (getResources(), R.drawable.blossom))));
            dataIterator = blossomVector.iterator();
            blossomNum++;
            Log.v(TAG, "Number of Blossoms =" + blossomNum);
        }
    };


    private synchronized void DrawBlossoms(Canvas c) // method to draw flowers on screen and test for collision
    {
        Canvas canvas = c;
        dataIterator = blossomVector.iterator();
        while (dataIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Blossom tempBlossom = dataIterator.next();
            tempBlossom.Draw(canvas);
            if (tempBlossom.hit(box_x,box_y, box_x + boxWidth, box_y + boxHeight, blossomVector) == true)
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "ITERATOR WORKS!");
                dataIterator.remove();
                currentScore += 100;
            }

            if (tempBlossom.dropped() == true)
            {
                dataIterator.remove();
                Log.v(TAG, "Blossom dropped");
                lives--;
            }
            if (lives == 0)
            {
                // stop the thread that makes blossoms
                game = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), HighScore.class);
                getContext().startActivity(intent);
                try {
                    thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Board.java:

```
public class Board extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new BoardView(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

HighScore.java:

```
public class HighScore extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);
        Button enter = new Button(this);
        enter.setText("Enter");

        l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        l1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edit.setText("Enter your name!");
        edit.isInEditMode();
        l1.setId(1);

        l1.addView(edit);
        l1.addView(enter);

        setContentView(l1);

    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): ANR in com.thesis.sakurame (com.thesis.sakurame/.HighScore)
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): Load: 0.98 / 0.58 / 0.39
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): CPU usage from 9073ms to 72ms ago:
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   system_server: 15% = 7% user + 7% kernel / faults: 127 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   adbd: 6% = 0% user + 5% kernel
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   thesis.sakurame: 5% = 3% user + 1% kernel / faults: 175 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   logcat: 2% = 0% user + 1% kernel
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   re-initialized>: 1% = 1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 18 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   d.process.acore: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   id.defcontainer: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   d.process.media: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 9 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.launcher: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   com.svox.pico: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   com.android.mms: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.email: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   .quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   m.android.music: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   re-initialized>: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66):   android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7 minor
05-09 21:29:54.723: ERROR/ActivityManager(66): TOTAL: 37% = 15% user + 21% kernel + 0% irq + 1% softirq
```

Comment: you have to post the code and the stacktrace.

Comment: Okay I've just edited it to show my code.

Comment: What about the stacktrace?  Please show the full logcat log for the time around the error.

Comment: okay I did it, but it didn't format nicely. But it's there.

Comment: The logcat says the ANR reason is 'keyDispatchingTimedOut`. If you google for that you might find some useful info.

Comment: I already know that is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. Doesn't it have to do with my UIThread?